# Tab Filter : how to get a static URL

Tags: filter, tabs

how to open a specific tab using a external URL, without a click
would like to get some help.

```
<ul class="filters" data-bs-toggle="buttons">
    <li class="btn active">
        <input type="radio">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">All Tests</a> 
    </li>
    <li data-filter=".General"  class="btn">
        <input type="radio" id="general" >
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">General</a> 
    </li>
    <li data-filter=".Business" class="btn">
        <input type="radio">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Premium</a> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
<li class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 Business m-b30">
    <div >
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>para</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: make it more clear what you want, as i understand you have a tab system and with some URLs you want to open a particular tab am i right?

Comment: correct, 
want to run a campaign to promote Business tab, 
what is the static URL for Business tab

eg : anchor #Business tab

Comment: you have to use javascript

Answer (score 0):

This is a demo code showing how you can handel the situation,basically what I have done is I assigned id to my items which will get the active class basically that particular div on which a click will open the tab,
Now I check the url parameters after page load and check if tabid is there and according to it I just give the element active class,

```
<script>
var execute = function () {
  var tabid=new URL(location.href).searchParams.get("tabid")
if(tabid){
document.getElementById(tabid).classList.toggle('active')
}
};

if ( !!(window.addEventListener) ){
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", execute)}
else{ // MSIE
  window.attachEvent("onload", execute)}
</script>
```